# Order of events when opening a presentation in PowerPoint?

Tags: vb.net, events, vsto, add-in, powerpoint

I'm kinda confused about the order of events in VSTO when opening a new PowerPoint presentation. Does anyone know it? Google gave me nothing.

Thanks in advance,

Léster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chirag Dalal has a web page that lists the events, the versions of PPT that support them and their order.

http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/events_version.html

I've no idea how this might relate to VSTO, but if it's trapping all of the events that PowerPoint throws, that should get you headed in the right direction.

Another useful approach would be to set up a little eventhandler app that logs or otherwise displays all events that PPT throws.  That would answer your current question and would be handy when other questions re event order come up.